# generate file and populate values

Tags: bash, automation, puppet, auto-generate

I'm tasked with creating about a hundred files for use with puppet. I'm creating .yaml files with unique filenames that will contain site-specific IP and hostname information, these must have the same format (ideally from a template).

I want to create a file generator that fills in variables for IP, subnet, network, and hostname from an input file (.csv?) What's the best way to approach this?

sample format:

```
---

network::interfaces::interfaces:
    eth0:
       method: 'static'
       address: '10.20.30.1'
       netmask: '255.255.240.0'
       broadcast: '10.20.30.255'
       network: '10.20.30.0'
       gateway: '10.20.30.1'
network::interfaces::auto:
    - 'eth0'

hosts::host_entries:
  HOSTNAME:
      ip: '10.20.30.2'
hosts::purge_hosts: true

dhcpd::range_start: '10.20.30.11'
dhcpd::range_stop: '10.20.30.240'
dhcpd::gateway: '10.20.30.1'

hornetq::site: 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a skeleton like this:

```
network::interfaces::interfaces:
  eth0:
    method: 'static'
    address: '__IP__'
    netmask: '__MASK__'
    broadcast: '__BC__'
    network: '__NET__'
    gateway: '__GW__'
```

etc.

Generate files with a loop like

```
cat input-file | while read OUTPUT IP MASK BC NET GW ; do
    sed -e s/__IP__/$IP/ \
        -e s/__MASK__/$MASK/ \
        -e s/__BC__/$BC/ \
        -e s/__NET__/$NET/ \
        -e s/__GW__/$GW/ \
        <$SKELETON >$OUTPUT
done
```

This assumes that the fileds in the input file are separated by whitespace, with the name of the respective output file in the first column.